# Wordpress Hook: post loaded

Tags: php, wordpress, post, hook

I need to run a function for set some tags via post id when a post loaded.
Is there any hook that lets me check post id when the post loaded ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Action hook you are looking for is [the_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/the_post). This hook is fired after post object is created.

Quick example:

```
<?php
function some_post_action( $post_object ) {
    // your function here, use $post_object->ID to access post id
}
add_action( 'the_post', 'some_post_action' );
?>
```

Comment: Here’s the updated link for [the_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_post/)